# Saving data to file in line by line from XML in PHP

Tags: php

I am getting data from another website, removing what I don't need. And would like to store the information I gathered to a file. I have done everything I need but my file writes array every line

Here is the code I am working on:

```
    $xml = simplexml_load_file('website.xml');

    $item_array = array();
    $item_array[0] = 0;
    $item_array[1] = 2;
    $item_array[2] = 4;
    $item_array[3] = 6;
    $item_array[4] = 8;
    $item_array[5] = 9;
    $item_array[6] = 10;
    $item_array[7] = 11;
    $item_array[8] = 12;
    $item_array[9] = 13;
    $item_array[10] = 14;
    $item_array[11] = 15;
    $item_array[12] = 16;

    $patterns = array();
    $patterns[0] = '/Sum It Up/';
    $patterns[1] = '/=/';
    $patterns[2] = '/Powerball/';
    $patterns[3] = '/MegaBall/';
    $patterns[4] = '/Megaplier/';
    $patterns[5] = '/Bonus Ball/';

    $print = array();
    foreach($item_array as $news){
    echo $xml->channel->item[$news]->title.'<br>';
    $new_string = $xml->channel->item[$news]->description;
    $new_string = preg_replace("/[^A-Za-z0-9 ]/", '', $new_string);
    $new_string = preg_replace($patterns, '', $new_string);
    echo $new_string.'<br>';
    $print[] = array($new_string);
    }

    $filename = 'numbers.txt';
    $handle = fopen($filename, 'w');
    @$output = implode("\r\n", $print);
    fwrite($handle, $output);
    fclose($handle);
```

I just want to keep the numbers as array and write the numbers to a file in line by line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the discussion below, the problem solved finally. Here should use `$print[] = $new_string` to make sure `$print` is one level array. Then you can using `var_export` or custom style to print it line by line. `$print[]` means to add an item into this array, if the item is an array already, $print will be an 2 level array.

-----Old Answer-----

Using [serialize()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php) function, it can serialize an array to string, and then you can write it to a file. Using [unserialize()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php) can make the string back to array.

Comment: So where  would  I put that

Comment: change **$output = implode("\r\n", $array);** to **$ouput = serialize($array);**

Comment: But now it is writing everything all weird with `a:13:{i:0;a:1:{i:0;s:21:`

Comment: it's the serialized result. and it can be  write to a file in one line. It isn't you want? I see the title is "saving array to file".

Comment: What if I need data in line by line. Does it need to be a string to write to file?

Comment: If you want to write it as PHP code style, pls try `var_export($array, true)`, and if you want a custom line by line style, pls using foreach to read each item and print into output file in your own format.

Comment: I think i have an array inside another array, or my first value is array.

Comment: `$print[] = $new_string;` is the correct way. Sorry guys figured it out. I had an array inside another array.

Comment: Yes, using `[]` means to add an item in this array. So, is there any problem now?

Comment: No, change your answer to my edited one so i can accept it  as answer.

Comment: my file is displaying 2 spaces in between the data. How do i remove just 1 space.

Comment: Do you mean replace multiple spaces to one space in a string? try `$str = preg_replace('#([\s]{2,})#', ' ',$str);`

Answer (score 0):

in my way ,vbs encode VS json_encode is all right,serialize is also a choice,if you don't mind the file size